# How to make a method that is used from another view available on another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have the shopping cart, I am trying to get the total cost calculated for items on the view called `CartIndexViewModel` to be displayed on the view called "completed". When i use the view bag it doesn't show up. Here is part of my `CartIndexViewModel` where the total price is calculated.

```
@model MovieModels.ModelClasses.CartIndexViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Movie Store: Your Cart";
  ViewBag.Cost = Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("R0.00");
}
```

Now i want to move the total cost, or call the method Cart.ComputeTotalValue() on this view

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "MovieStore: Order Submitted";
}

<h2>Thanks!</h2>
Thanks for placing your order. We'll ship your goods as soon as possible.


<h3>Payment is as as follows:</h3>
<div class="form-group">

<label>Total Price:</label> ViewBag.Cost = Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("R0.00");

</div>
```

Comment: Your code is not even attempting to display that information.

Answer (score 0):

Like Andrew Barber said, you do not even attempt to display the total cost. Otherwise something like `Total Cost: <span>@ViewBag.Cost</span>` should be visible somewhere in your code.

My guess is that to get to the Order Submitted page, a POST is involved somewhere between submitting the order (presumably by clicking a button somewhere in the cart) and displaying the 'Order Submitted' confirmation page.

Since HTTP is kinda stateless and the ViewBag does not carry state across requests, setting the Cost property in the ShowCart request will not do you any good: it will not be available in the next request (the POST that lands you on the order submitted page).

The cart though is probably stored somewhere (a cookie, the database or whatever), and it is converted to an Order (which again I presume is stored in the database).

So after creating the Order you should now have the total cost available, since to do that you've either accessed the cart somewhere and the items in it; or at the very least you have a reference to the cart (eg the Cart.Id) which you can use to pull the actual data and display the cost